# What is part of speech of "fifteen minutes" in "She is fifteen minutes late"?

Tags: grammar

Look at this sentence "**She is fifteen minutes late**"

"**is**" is linking verb & "**late**" is adjective.
Then I don't know whether "**fifteen minutes**" is noun or adverb of time?

Comment: "Fifteen minutes" is a noun phrase with "minutes" as head and "fifteen" as determiner. The NP is modifying the adjective "late".

Comment: @BillJ That looks like an answer to me!

Answer (score 1):

It is an adverb phrase of time together with a determiner and functions in the like manner we are habituated to use adverbials like, Sunday morning/in the evening/at the weekend. If we shift the adverb phrase to the end we would get a sentence like this:-

• He is late 'by fifteen minutes.

To be true, minute,hour,home — though nouns — bear adverbial properties. Fifteen minutes – is an adverbial together with 'late'. 'Late', an adjective is modified by this adverbial.

Comment: An adverb or adverb group of time is a when-indication. "15 metres" is no when-indication.

Comment: @rogermue an adverb/adverbial of time is a when-indication as well as 'how-long' or 'how-often' indication. Cf. He is always busy(how long) and seldom(how often) plays.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a number of adjectives such as long, high, deep, tall, late can have a complement/modifier indicating a measurement:

ten metres long, six feet tall, 15 minutes late etc.

http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adj_modifiers.html